# ImportError: No module named wget

Tags: python, macos, wget

Please help me to find reason on MacOS why when I including library

import wget

I'm getting error

```
File "/Users/xx/python/import.py", line 4, in <module>
    import wget
ImportError: No module named wget
```

This library is installed

```
xx$ pip3 install wget
Requirement already satisfied: wget in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (3.2)
```

I just suppose that some path is not set, but I don't know how to prove this.

Please help me find solution for this problem.

Comment: maybe you use python2 ?

Comment: yeah maybe multiple versions of python installed.

Comment: Do you have a shebang in your python file? Or is that not a thing in MacOS?

Comment: macOS uses shebang, Yep. #!/usr/bin/env python3

Comment: Also a useful thing: start a python (2 or 3), and at the interpreter prompt, run: help(), then: modules. It'll print a list of all the modules it sees.

Comment: I'm using to edit and run code Sublime Text or Visual Studio Code.
I tried both version 2 and 3 and result is the same.

Answer (score 17):

Try `pip install wget`, maybe you’re using python 2

Comment: xx$ pip install wget
Requirement already satisfied: wget in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (3.2)

Answer (score 4):

With pip3 you are installing module for python 3,
It can b that you have both versions of python 2 and 3 and you your environment is pointing default to python 2

Check python version or install wget for python 2

```
python -V    
pip install wget
```

Comment: xx$ pip install wget
Requirement already satisfied: wget in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (3.2)

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-wget
```

Comment: Hi Alex, avoid giving one liners as answers. Always try to explain what you are posting. :)

Answer (score 1):

this should not be the case, but check if *site-packages* is in the path for accessing modules

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
[..., '...\\python3.6\\lib\\site-packages', ...] ## if this is here I cannot help you
```

if not, try repairing python
you can do that by clicking setup file (one with which you installed in the first place),
and among 3 options click *repair*

Comment: import sys      - works just fine without any errors

Comment: path is : /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages

Comment: not `import sys`. check if your path is in `sys.path`

Comment: @Superior possibly an easier way to accomplish the same is to add that directory to `PYTHONPATH` before starting python: `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/site-packages` from the command prompt will do it. At any rate, this is certainly the most correct answer here.

Answer (score 1):

If you process the python script by command:

```
python import.py
```

or

```
python3 import.py
```

it should work.

But if you process the executable python script by command:

```
./import.py ENTER
```

then incldue as the first line of the script import.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Comment: This doesn't answer what's been asked.

Comment: @NitinNain really, OP would need to provide more information to make the original question answerablle with any level of certainty... What has me confused is how this question has earned 5 upvotes and nearly 14k views in less than 2 years...

Comment: No, please read the question. The OP doesn't have a problem in starting the python script, but in importing `wget`.

Comment: I did read the question. OP doesn't actually show the content of `imoprt.py` so we can only speculate about what is happening.

Comment: python3 import.py worked for me as I changed import.py to the name of the python file I am trying to run. i.e "python3 project.py". Given project.py as the name of my python file.

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install wget
```

if in colab use:

```
!pip install wget
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command worked for me in Jupyter Lab

```
!pip install wget
```

Hope this does help!

Answer (score 0):

In Jupyter Lab, although my Python was 3.9 but it was using 3.7 paths (I have multiple Pythons installed):

```py
import sys

sys.path

['D:\\Projects',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37',
 '',
 'C:\\Users\\John\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
 'C:\\Users\\John\\.ipython']
```

So I did `!pip3.7 install --user wget`, and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently and using `python3` instead of `py` worked for me.